# How to map unique ID,ID combos into legible numbered lines in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, recursion, io

I want to create a non-recursive way of creating numbering that resembles --

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.3
2
2.1  etc etc (these items can be infinitely deep)
```

The only identifying information I have is a two number ID.  The first ID is the ID that identifies the item, and the second ID identifies what it belongs to and zero is always the document root.

For example:

```
123,0
456,123
789,123
777, 789
999, 123
888,0
444,888
```

Would be translated into --

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.2.1
1.3
2
2.1
```

The data is read inline.  I do not know what comes after it, only what came in front of it.
I believe this should be simple but for some reason I am having a hard time coming up with an efficient solution.  Note:  The items will always come in order.  For example I will never get item 1.2 before I get item 1.1, etc.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want it recursive? This sounds like one of recursion's strong points here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items comes in the correct order, a stack will be fine:

```
public class Item {
    private int id;
    private int parentId;

    public Item(int id, int parentId) {
        this.id = id;
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    public int getId() { return id; }
    public int getParentId() { return parentId; }
}

public class NumberedItem {
    private Item item;
    private int childCount;
    private String number;

    public NumberedItem(Item item, String number) {
        this.item = item;
        this.childCount = 0;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public Item getItem() { return item; }
    public String getNumber() { return number; }

    /* package */ int incrementChildCount() {
        return ++childCount;
    }
}

public NumberedItemIterator implements Iterable<NumberedItem> {
    private Iterator<Item> items;
    private Stack<NumberedItem> numberStack;

    public NumberedItemIterator(Iterable<Item> itemsIterable) {
        items = itemsIterable.iterator();
        numberStack = new Stack<NumberedItem>();
        numberStack.push(new NumberedItem(null, null));
    }

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return items.hasNext();
    }

    public NumberedItem next() {
        Item current = items.next();
        int parentId = current.getParentId();

        NumberedItem parent = null;
        while (!numberStack.empty()) {
            NumberedItem candidate = numberStack.peek();
            if (candidate.getItem().getId() == parentId) {
                parent = candidate;
                break;
            }
            numberStack.pop();
        }

        if (parent == null) throw new RuntimeException("Inconsistent ordering");

        String number = Integer.toString(parent.incrementChildCount());
        if (parent.getNumber() != null) {
            number = parent.getNumber() + "." + number;
        }

        NumberedItem result = new NumberedItem(current, number);

        numberStack.push(result);

        return result;
    }

    public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it works, but I actually came up with an even simpler solution.  I would push the string (parentID+lineNumber) onto the stack with a delimiter.  This allowed each pop to always have the information I needed.  I would pop the parentID, increment the line number and push it back on to the stack, then push the child onto the stack.

Answer (score 0):

My algorithm here would be:

- As you read each pair `(x, y)`, insert `x` into a tree as a child of `y`
- To print, run a depth-first recursion over the tree. If you want to do this without recursion, you could use a stack implementation instead.

Of course, this is a very general sketch - plenty of choices to make as far as specific implementation!

Comment: I actually began this with a Stack as it seemed like the easiest solution.  I think part of the issue is I need the data read in real time, in line.  I cant create a full picture, the iterate over it later.

Comment: this seems clearly impossible. for example, consider the sequence of inputs: (1,0), (2,1), (3,0), (4,1); you would want this to print 1, 1.1, 1.2, 2; but when you see (3, 0), you need the future knowledge that (4,1) is coming to know not to go ahead and just print 2. Or a simpler example: (1,0), (2,0), (3,1); this should print 1, 1.1, 2; but you need to know not to just print "2" when you read (2,0).

Comment: Not exactly, since 0 is always document root, in the last example, 1,0, 2,0, 3,1 could never exist.  The items are in order in that nothing would come between 1 and 1.1, and that example would be 1, 2, 1.1.  I am not saying its not impossible, but I want to make sure you understand the example.  (as in, I read the pairs from a document in the order they would appear once numbered, they just lack numbers and it has to be done in line, so I can't look ahead to know when I am done with a subset).